# Authenticate Camel REST API using Basic Authentication or oAuth token validation

Tags: spring-security, apache-camel, netty, spring-camel

I am new to Camel (on Spring Boot) and implementing REST API using "netty-http" component.

For Basic auth on a service, I know that we can validate the headers in a .process method in the route, but I am not sure if that is a best practice.

I wanted to know if anyone can share some info on implementing Basic Auth or oAuth validation on the Camel Routes using spring security.

Java DSL Code below:

```
@Component
public class RetrieveRestAPI extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    RetrieveData retrieveData;



    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        restConfiguration()
                .component("netty-http") 
                .port("{{http.port}}")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
                ;

        //TODO: Basic Auth
        //TODO: oAuth token validation..

        rest("/{{BasePath}}/{DataId}")
                .get()
                .to("direct:fetchData");

        from("direct:fetchData")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        log.info("some code here..");
                    }
                })

                .end();
    }
```

Thanking you,
V.

Comment: Did this guide not help? https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/spring-security.html